# Пользовательский тип данных в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли какая-то разница между переменной таблицей и тем, если бы эта переменная таблица являлась бы пользовательским типом?

Например, в производительности и т п.

Я знаю, что пользовательский тип данных мощно возвращать и передавать в функции.

Comment: перефразируйте, пожалуйста

Answer (score 4):

Да, естественно есть отличия - UDTT это все-таки не полноценные таблицы. Кроме ограничений, перечисленных в [User-Defined Table Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx), вроде

- невозможности поменять структуру пользователького типа после создания
- невозможности создать на пользовательском типе некластерный индекс (с оговорками)

есть еще одно важное отличие, напрямую влияющее на производительность: SQL Server не поддерживает статистику на колонках при [передаче значения пользовательского типа в качестве параметра](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). Т.е. вправе считать, что в вашем переданном параметре [всегда лежит примерно одна строка](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/table-variable-perf-fix). Это [немного починили в SQL Server 2014](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/improvements-table-variables-and-temporary-tables-sql-server-2014), но проблема иногда все еще проявляется.

На практике это означает что при использовании UDT и при использовании в тех же целях временной таблицы вы, возможно, получите разные планы выполнения для эквивалентных запросов. И, соответственно, разную производительность, причем UDT не обязательно покажет худший результат.